# How to read attribute value from JsonObject

Tags: json, xml, groovy

I have following xml, I want to read attribute `userReference` value from `JsonObject`

```html
<void property="someId">
<object class=com.someclass>
          <void method="add">
                <object class="com.xyz.data">
                 <void property="firstActivationDate">
                  <object class="java.util.Date">
                   <long>11122344000</long>
                  </object>
                 </void>
                 <void property="service">
                  <string>P2P</string>
                 </void>
                 <void property="status">
                  <object idref="newSerivice"/>
                 </void>
                </object>
               </void>
              </void>
              <void property="userId">
               <string>224662233412</string>
              </void>
              <void property="userReference">
               <string>224662233412</string>
              </void>
             </object>
         </void>
    </object>
</void>
```

I am doing something like this:

```
def content = parser.parse(xmlStream.getJSON()).getAsJsonObject()
def jsonObject = content.get(//what should be the node here ?)?.getAsJsonObject() 
if (jsonObject) { 
  userRef = jsonObject.get("userReference")?.getAsString() 
  }
```

I am confused about where to get jsonObject which encloses this attribute.

Comment: That's a strange question. JSON and XML are very different data description languages. How do you expect JSON to correctly parse XML???

Comment: @cadrian , my bad, consider it as `JSON String` instead of `xml` and I have parsed it to tree.

Comment: @Sajjad, this question seems really unclear. Could you please rewrite it and provide a runnable example?

Comment: @tim_yates - yes it's soap response.

Comment: @Sajjad It's a soap response, but your groovy code is not in SOAP UI groovy testSTep isn't? anyway can you provide more context... what parser are you using?

Comment: @albciff  - I am using `com.google.gson.JsonParser`.
Yes my code in not SOAP UI testSTEP.
This is basically a soap response from which I needed to get a particular attribute value. I was finding it difficult to locate the exact object under which this attribute exists, since there are multiple objects enclosing this particular attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're using [`com.google.gson.JsonParser`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) from gson library, however I'm not sure since there is not enough context in your question.

Anyway why you don't use [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) from gdk to achieve your goal.

Supposing that you want to get the text value inside the follow node of your xml:

```
<void property="userReference">
   <string>224662233412</string>
</void>
```

You can use the follow code (previously correcting the XML to be well formed):

```
import groovy.xml.*
def xmlText = '''<void>
    <object>
        <void>
            <void method="add">
                <object class="com.xyz.data">
                    <void property="firstActivationDate">
                        <object class="java.util.Date">
                            <long>11122344000</long>
                        </object>
                    </void>
                    <void property="service">
                        <string>P2P</string>
                    </void>
                    <void property="status">
                        <object idref="newSerivice"/>
                    </void>
                </object>
            </void>
        </void>
        <void property="userId">
            <string>224662233412</string>
        </void>
        <void property="userReference">
            <string>224662233412</string>
        </void>
    </object>
</void>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlText)
def foo = xml.depthFirst().find { it.name() == 'void' && it.@property == 'userReference'}
println foo.text() // 224662233412
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Following solved it for me.

Basically what we need to do is, instead of getting the `immediate parent object` to that `attribute`, we need to get the first most `parent object` to that `attribute`.

In this case `immediate parent object` can be obtained through `someid`

```html
def jsonObject = tr.get("someId")?.getAsJsonObject() //get parent object which encloses child object, that child object encloses the attribute.
userRef = jsonObject.get("userReference")?.getAsString() // get required attribute directly from immediate parent object.
```